# What are the risks to exclude lxcfs folder from ubuntu server backup?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, rsync, lxc

I'm making full Ubuntu 18.04 server backups with rsync, which has no permission to copy files from lxcfs folder. I understand it has something to do with virtualisation, which I'm not consciously using. However, I've got several Docker and Snap applications. 
What are the risks not to backup lxcfs folders of a pretty standard web-server setup?

Comment: I'm in the exact same position... Did you ever figure out an answer to this?

Comment: Not really. It is mindblowing how the OS, which is created for servers, does not have a clear system backup solution. It should be preconfigured and enabled during OS installation.